# Mongodb server selection error: connection monitor closed

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

MongoServerSelectionError: connection  to ******* closed.
The day I installed mongodb
I added IP address, database user, connection type: mongodb shell, mongosh, run using cmd. It was working fine, but since then this is the error I'm getting:
`MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to ******* closed.` whenever I try to connect.I run connection string, type my password and then this error: MongoServerSelectionError. How to resolve?